# efficient way for a selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

i got this structure:

```
<ul class="depth-one">
    <li>Category 1 <span class="do">+</span>
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li > Category 1.1 <span class="do">+</span>
                <ul class="depth-three">
                    <li>Category 1.2.1</li>
                    <li>Category 1.2.2</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> Category 1.2</li>
            <li> Category 1.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li> Category 2 <span class="do">+</span>
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li>Category 2.1</li>
            <li>Category 2.2</li>
            <li>Category 2.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Category 3 <span class="do">+</span>
        <ul class="depth-two">
            <li>Category 3.1</li>
            <li>Category 3.2</li>
            <li>Category 3.3</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

with that CSS:

```
ul{
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
ul li{
    width:220px

}
.depth-one{

}
.depth-two{
    display:none;
}
.depth-three{
    display:none;
}

.do{
    float:right;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:blue;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

What I want to do is, whenever I click on the class "do" (the spans) I would like to toggle the closet UL element.

How can I pick the closet UL element to the span using jQuery, so I can use the functions slideUp and slideDown to toggle it?

My Idea was to use the function next(), but I think that there is a more generic way to do it.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by more generic? The less generic method is the better but if you want in some way keep your DOM more maintanable, you could use:  `.nextAll('ul')` or `.siblings('ul')`. You could combinate this method with `.first()` depending case of use and DOM

Comment: Use jQuery eq method and pass the index to it. It Reduces the set of matched elements to the one at the specified index.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, the `.next()` is actually perfect

```
$('.do').on('click', function() {
    $(this).next('ul').slideToggle().find('ul:visible').slideUp(); // According to your comment; hide all the visible successors of type ul.
    $(this).text( $(this).text() == '+' ? '-' : '+' ); // Alter the caption (which I guess you want to do as well) :-)
});
```

**EDIT:** Added hide for all child ul's to match your comment.

Comment: well, guess there isnt another way than using the next() function :-)
Your solution works perfectly fine, but there is one slight problem, if I expand Category 1, and then expand category 1.1, and then CLOSE category 1, and then re-open category 1, category 1.1 is still opened.
fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uXA7E/

Comment: @kfirba Typically, you should have put this comment in your question which would be then a bit clearer

Comment: @kfirba I believe many menus will re-open the same way they were closed, so this is not unusual behaviour.

Comment: @kfirba Check my edit. It will ensure that all child ul's are being hided, upon expansion/closing of the parent.

Comment: thanks @Eric ! I have just seen your edit.
NVM, understood :-)

Comment: `$(this).next('ul').slideToggle().find('ul:visible').slideUp().prev('.do').text('+'); /`

Comment: @roasted thanks!
I got a question related to your code, when you are using the function .prev('.do'), previous to what? the visible UL element? or prev to this? and then, why use an argument '.do'?

Comment: @kfirba previous to nested ULs, not 'this'. Selector in prev() here is optionnal but by habit i always filter transversal method for more clarity

Comment: @roasted can you confirm this:
.prev() is related to the *visible ULs that are* ***in*** *the UL which is coming after the current* ***.do*** *element?*

jQuery representation: 
`$(this).next('ul').find('ul:visible').prev('.do')`

is this correct?

Comment: @kfirba ya, find returns matched set of elements, so with chaining, .prev() is applied to this matched set. To apply it to the element refered with 'this' you could use '.end()' which here would have no meaning but this is for the example. And to apply to both, you could use .addBack() method

Comment: @roasted I see.

When we used .find(), we were returned with match of elements, now, when I use .slideUp() function on them, I do not change the match of element that has been returned from the function .find(), therefore I am able to do another operation on the matched element, such as the .prev('.do') and effect the same match elements even tho they are now HIDDEN thanks to the .slideUp() function.

Is that correct?

Comment: @kfirba mostly all jquery methods keep chaining `return this.each()` so slideUp() apply to .find() elements will return this same match of elements. Then .pev() is apply to it. See there: http://jsfiddle.net/YKSB9/  And this is using .end() to refers again to this: http://jsfiddle.net/YKSB9/1/  As there is already three new sets of elements, then we need to use `.end().end().end()` Unreadable but still for the example. Unfortunately, .end() method doesn't accept a selector which could be in some case quite interesting

Comment: I see, so basically, what you are trying to say is, that **every** function returns march of element, so .slideUp() returned the match of element that it has affected, and then we used .prev() on that match elements. is that correct :-)?
and btw, thanks a lot! really really helped me

Comment: @kfirba As soon as a jquery method returns a jquery set of elements, method used after it in the chain are apply to it. So ya, you are correct!

Comment: @roasted thanks a lot! you were talking generally, I was trying to hold on to an exist example :) btw, is there any way i can check if a method does return set of elements? or every method does return set of elements?

Comment: @kfirba You have to read the DOC for each method but if the method is supposed to return a jquery object, then yes. e.g, if using get(), an array of DOM nodes is returned, so no more jquery methods can be applied to it, DOM methods are then required (javascript function which doesn't keep chaining)

Comment: @roasted roger that, understood!
so I can keep on chaining only if i returned with **jQuery** objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) method

Example:

```
$(".do").click(function () {
    $(this).next("ul").slideToggle()
});
```

Comment: Sorry, Eric's answer wasn't there when I started but I got distracted half way through typing it

Comment: So that's ok, i know what you mean ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(".do").click(function () {
    $(this).next().closest("ul").slideToggle();
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/4V7fx/)